# TestDome League table - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, lambda

I came across a question as below to be executed in Python:

The LeagueTable class tracks the score of each player in a league. After each game, the player records their score with the record_result function.

The player's rank in the league is calculated using the following logic:

1.The player with the highest score is ranked first (rank 1). The player with the lowest score is ranked last.

2.If two players are tied on score, then the player who has played the fewest games is ranked higher.

3.If two players are tied on score and number of games played, then the player who was first in the list of players is ranked higher.

Implement the player_rank function that returns the player at the given rank.

```
    from collections import Counter
    from collections import OrderedDict


    class LeagueTable:
        def __init__(self, players):
            self.standings = OrderedDict([(player, Counter()) for player in players])

        def record_result(self, player, score):
            self.standings[player]['games_played'] += 1
            self.standings[player]['score'] += score

        def player_rank(self, rank):
            return None


    table = LeagueTable(['Mike', 'Chris', 'Arnold'])
    table.record_result('Mike', 2)
    table.record_result('Mike', 3)
    table.record_result('Arnold', 5)
    table.record_result('Chris', 5)
    print(table.player_rank(1))
```

I wrote a long solution of over 20 lines for it which works but then I found a shorter code for the function as below:

```
    def player_rank(self, rank):
        print(self.standings)
        ranking = sorted(self.standings, key=lambda p: (
        -self.standings[p]['score'], self.standings[p]['games_played'], self.standings[p]['pos']))
        return ranking[rank - 1]
```

Can someone help me understand how this works ?

P.S: I'm just a newbie, beginning to learn programming.

Link to the original question.

https://www.testdome.com/d/python-interview-questions/9

Answer (score 5):

For the Solution:

```
def player_rank(self, rank):
    print(self.standings)
    ranking = sorted(self.standings, key=lambda p: (
    -self.standings[p]['score'], self.standings[p]['games_played'], 
self.standings[p]['pos']))
    return ranking[rank - 1]
```

The whole function basically sorts out the players based on the key, First

```
-self.standing[p]['score']
```

Get descending list based on 'score' which means the highest to lowest, then

```
self.standings[p]['games_played']
```

Which sort the previous list again into ascending order based on 'games_played'

```
self.standings[p]['pos']
```

This one should be sorting the list based on the order of an ordered collection, I think you missed some other portion of the code with 'pos'

and now you have a list that have all the ranks sorted out, you return the particular player that has the particular rank

Answer (score 2):

As of in 2019 for the problem, 4 test cases passed.

```
    def player_rank(self, rank):
    srt = sorted(
        self.standings.items(),
        key=lambda kv: (
              -kv[1]['score'],
              kv[1]['games_played'],
        ),
        reverse=False)

    # print(srt)
    return srt[rank - 1][0]
```